# Javascript, only works with eventhandler

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

Every time my page gets loaded I want some javascript to get executed if a new message is in the TempData.

```
window.onload = function () {  
      $.jGrowl('Hello world!');
};
```

And that works fine. But do I have to put the call inside a windows.onload or other eventhandlers, because if I do it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript>
$.jGrowl('Hello world!');
</script>
```

it won´t work
It comes up with a

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I have been trying to put the javascript in the bottom of the page to make sure averything else is loaded first

Hope for some help
Jakob

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  Is there an error on the debugging console?  The most common reason for this is because `$` isn't defined at the time you try to run that line of code.  Is it?

Comment: "it won´t work" doesn't describe your problem. What you expect your code to do, and what it does instead?

Comment: I have edit my post with some description of the problem

Comment: Probably someplace after your plugin has loaded should do the trick

Comment: Could it be that missing closing quote on the type attribute?

Comment: The missing closing quote is just a typo :)

Comment: Now a have putting it just above </body></html> and it still gives a script438

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload

The problem is the code fires before the DOM has loaded.

Here's a related article.. [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

Comment: Does `jGrowl` require the DOM to be loaded before it can be used?

Comment: That could be the case. That the DOM needs to be loaded before you can manipulate with it

Answer (score 0):

According to their example [this](http://jsbin.com/mufevi/1/edit) should be working perfectly... I tried to unwrap the call, the best I could do is remove the outter self executing function...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jgrowl/1.2.12/jquery.jgrowl.min.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-jgrowl/1.2.12/jquery.jgrowl.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.jGrowl("Hello world!");
});
</script>
```

My guess is the library uses dom ready so its not available to jquery until after dom ready has executed.

Here is [a JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/mufevi/1/edit)

Comment: Ok I found out what was the problem. It did´nt load the the jgrowl library. Why it worked in the onload i have no idea about. But its working now. Thanks for all the replies